# Отправить message из content script в скрипт конкретной devtools панели

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension

Я пишу расширение для chrome которое создает дополнительную вкладку в devtools. Мне нужно чтобы при загрузке страницы и при изменении ее структуры, контент скрипт отправлял сообщение скрипту вкладки в devtools которая открыта на этой странице. Либо же можно отправить всем возможным скриптам сообщение, но как тогда на стороне скрипта вкладки в панели понять что запрос пришел именно с текущего контент скрипта, а не с любого другого.
**content.js**

```
window.onload = function () {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage('gikbdbdjmjjejbnclglhfcidffdgibof', {message: 'loaded'})

    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', function () {
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage('gikbdbdjmjjejbnclglhfcidffdgibof', {message: 'changed'})
    })
}
```

Это я отправляю сообщение всем, а как поймать его в конкретной вкладке на панели devtools либо же отправить конкретной, я не знаю.